# Simple thread example needed

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

Given the following requirements, could someone post a very simple code sample illustrating how you could use multi-threading, and at the same time properly utilize locks to keep the shared data "safe"?

Say you declare an integer x to be 100. Then, you want to spawn off 10 threads to each perform some action.  As each thread completes the action, it decrements x. I know you can use interlocked for this, but wouldn't you also need a lock when you evaluate the condition? In other words, you need to make sure that x is greater than 0 before you perform the action.

Answer (score 4):

You can wrap every access to `x` with the `lock` keyword:

```
private object xLock = new object();

...

lock (xLock)
{
   // Any read or write access to x
}
```

This will ensure that all accesses to x are atomic, and there is no danger related to thread-safety.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to write simple multithreaded programs, consider using the parallel extensions in C# 4.0.

Plain multithreaded programs with locks and mutable shared data are **never** simple.

Answer (score 2):

You probably don't want to decrement the counter after the operation has finished, as the counter could be 1, all 10 threads would check it, see that it's greater than zero, and start performing the action, only to all decrement it on completion.

You can use [Interlocked.Decrement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1z4b2e5y.aspx) to decrement the counter and check its value before performing the action without locking:

```
int temp = Interlocked.Decrement(x);

if(temp >= 0) //temp is the decremented value
{
    //perform action
}
```

Comment: yes, but what if the action fails. I don't want to decrement.

Comment: The possibility of actions failing makes it a little more complicated.  You might want to look into the parallel extensions in C# 4.0 as jdv suggested in his answer and see if that suits your requirements before trying to design something yourself.  Multithreaded programs can very easily get very complicated very quickly.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use [Interlocked.CompareExchange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/801kt583.aspx).  Let's say you want to modify a shared variable called `Counter`.

```
int count = Counter;
if (count == 0)
    return;
if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref Counter, count-1, count) == count)
{
    // Counter was decremented.
    // perform your processing.
}
```

You can wrap that in a loop if you want your thread to process up to 10 items before it exits.

Note that the counter controls *entry* to the processing method.  That is, logically it works like this:

```
if (counter > 0)
{
    --counter;
    DoAction();
}
```

Your question seems to ask for something like:

```
if (counter > 0)
{
    DoAction();
    --counter;
}
```

But if you code it that way, then you'll likely call `DoAction` more than 100 times (or whatever the initial value of `counter` is) because other threads can start the action before the last one is done.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do your version of things just implement your own logic

```
lock(somecommonreference)
{
   if (x>0) x--;
}
```